# How to make this macro work as expected?

Tags: clojure

```
 (defmacro switch [choices choice] '(do (choices choice)))
 (macroexpand-1 '(switch {1 (print 1) 2 (print 2)} (+ 1 1)))

 gives: (do (choices choice))
```

Just to learn macros, I wanted to emulate switch case where I will give a dictionary having case as keys and code to execute as values.

I wanted (+ 1 1) to get evaluated as 2 and then be used as key to get codde to execute with do.

However the expanded macro gives us code which doesn't resolve choices and choice both.

I tried unquoting choice and choices, doesn't work.
What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unquoting does work, but you need to switch from the regular quote to syntax-quote (backtick) for your quoting:

```
(defmacro switch [choices choice]
  `(do (~choices ~choice)))
```

Note that the `do` here is unnecessary.

Note that with this version of `switch`, both `print` calls in your example will be evaluated, because they will simply appear as value expressions in a map literal in switch's output. To print conditionally, you'll have to use some conditional construct (`if`, `case` or something which expands to one of them). I'll also point out that the `choices` argument must be a literal map, or else the macro won't be able to get at the keys and values (and in any case the values would have been evaluated by the outer context).

Here's a version written with the above in mind:

```
(defmacro switch [choices choice]
  `(case ~choice ~@(apply concat choices)))
```

Example from the REPL:

```
user=> (switch {1 (print 1) 2 (print 2)} (+ 1 1))
2nil
```

(`2` is printed by the `print` call, `nil` is the return value.)

Comment: How is syntax-quoting diifferent from quoting ?

Comment: The primary difference is unquoting, withing a syntax-quote you can unquote as above. Another difference that comes up often is auto-gensyms to prevent inadvertent symbol capture. Fundamentally anything you can do with syntax quote you could do with quote and a fancy enough set of cons and concat calls.

Comment: It also resolves non-namespace-qualified symbols to Vars and replaces them by the namespace-qualified symbols naming those Vars in the output. (This can be prevented with a combination of unquoting with regular quote when it's inconvenient; most of the time, it's a great feature.)