# How to avoid map values from being evaluated in a macro?

Tags: clojure

I am writing a Clojure macro that should accept a map having some code as value with a key for it.

later on I would like to evaluate the code based on key provided.

How do I avoid map values from being evaluated before I do  ?
I dont want the whole map to be quoted as I would need keys to be evaluated.

I don't want to pass the code syntax quoted.

Is there a way for to make a macro quote the values inside of a map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, as pointed out in my answer to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556008/how-to-make-this-macro-work-as-expected) from two days ago, if the macro is to transform the map itself in any way, it will have to receive it as a map literal, rather than, say, a symbol naming a map-holding local. Well, strictly speaking you could also accept symbols and evaluate them for their global *compile-time* values; no way to get at the runtime values though.

If you're happy to accept literal maps only, then you can use the usual map transformation functions on them. For example, this macro will quote the values in the map literal passed in while leaving the keys unquoted:

```
(defmacro quote-vals [map-literal]
  (zipmap (keys map-literal)
          (map #(list 'quote %) (vals map-literal))))
```

From the REPL:

```
(quote-vals {(+ 1 2) (+ 1 2) (+ 3 4) (+ 3 4)})
;= {7 (+ 3 4), 3 (+ 1 2)}
```